# Dynamic table width with awk

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, grep, format

Is there a more sophisticated way to format a table using awk? The current code I have does not do entirely as I intended, if piped to `| column -t`, the PATTERN column gets all words tabbed.

```
main() {
    read -p "Enter a full path for search: " path
    read -p "Enter a pattern to search for: " pattern
    printf "\n"

    # Use process substitution to capture the grep output
    output=$(grep -inR "$pattern" "$path")

    if [ -n "$output" ]; then
        # Use awk to format the output into a table-like view
        echo "$output" | awk -F: 'BEGIN { printf "%-100s %-5s %-20s\n", "FILE", "LINE", "PATTERN"
                                      printf "%-100s %-5s %-20s\n", "----", "----", "-------" }
                                    { printf "%-100s %-5s %-20s\n", $1, $2, $3}' | column -t
    else
        echo "No matching results found."
    fi
}
```

The output:

```
FILE                                                                                    LINE  PATTERN                        
----                                                                                    ----  -------                        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/grep_usage.sh               32    #        Main  function        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/grep_usage.sh               72    #        Call  the       main  function
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/random_number_generator.sh  32    #        Main  function        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/random_number_generator.sh  37    #        Call  the       main  function
```

Comment: please dont use pictures unless its really necessary.

Comment: and please use a [repro].

Comment: We cant help you write a tool to parse input if you don't show us the input you need to parse.

Comment: Please post the content of `echo "$output"` _without awk_. `the PATTERN column gets all words tabbed.` Great, so first preprocess output and put separators where you want then, then call `column -t -s<the separator>`.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, the separator is ":", so it works perfectly now! /home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/basic/file_copy.sh:66:# Main function
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/basic/file_copy.sh:90:# Call the main function

Comment: If your results are small enough to fit in `awk`’s data structures, you could (rather obviously) gather them in arrays and then use an `END` clause to calculate the field width precisely (by looking at the whole output before printing it out).

Comment: Please don't multi-post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/765715/133219). Copying your question to a different site doesn't make it easier for us to help you parse input when you won't show us the input anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ { echo -e "FILE:LINE:PATTERN\n---:----:----"; cat file; } | 
   column -ts:


FILE                                                                                  LINE  PATTERN
---                                                                                   ----  ----
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/grep_usage.sh               32    # Main function        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/grep_usage.sh               72    # Call the main function
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/random_number_generator.sh  32    # Main function        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/random_number_generator.sh  37    # Call the main function
```

if you want to match the underline to the header word length, you will some additional code.

```
$ { echo -e "FILE:LINE:PATTERN" | awk '1;gsub(/[^:]/,"-")'; cat file; } | 
  column -ts:

FILE                                                                                  LINE  PATTERN
----                                                                                  ----  -------
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/grep_usage.sh               32    # Main function        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/grep_usage.sh               72    # Call the main function
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/random_number_generator.sh  32    # Main function        
/home/user/shell-scripting-ex/Shell-scripting/scripts/new/random_number_generator.sh  37    # Call the main function
```